# .htaccess redirects - how to handle "nested" strings?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Situation: a part of the product line was upgraded/enhanced with new features, resulting in the addition of "XL" to all model names.

Problem: need to redirect old URLs to new URLs, but the new URLs *contain* the old keywords + "XL", resulting in "too many redirects".

Example:
`RewriteRule ^.*(PRODUCT-001).*$ http://www.example.com/PRODUCT-001-XL [L,NC,R=301]`

How can I specify that I want **this exact string** to match, and not the rest of the URL?

E.g. "this rule should match *PRODUCT-001* but **not** *PRODUCT-001-XL*?

Comment: you should accept the answer if it solves your problem!

Answer (score 1):

The trailing `.*` allows for anything/nothing to be present after it. Remove that and your regex will match `PRODUCT-001` and not `PRODUCT-001-XL`.

```
RewriteRule ^.*(PRODUCT-001)$ http://www.example.com/PRODUCT-001-XL [L,NC,R=301]
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/tP8yq4/1 vs. https://regex101.com/r/tP8yq4/2

An alternative approach if you only wanted to block `-XL` would be a negative lookahead. You'll need to be using Apache 2+ for this.

```
^.*PRODUCT-001(?!-XL).*$
```

Third Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tP8yq4/3